# How to run a build server task under a specific user account?

Tags: authentication, testing, coded-ui-tests, azure-pipelines

I require my VSTS build server, or more accurately my build agent, to execute a task under a specific user account. Example:

[image]

One of my build steps tests the UI of an application. It requires to be logged in under a different account to be able to execute tests correctly. I cannot find anything in VSTS that allows me to configure that.

My current workaround is to run my tests in a different thread, started via a PowerShell command; however, this solution feels dirty, is fairly complicated, has limited live reporting and costs work to re-integrate the test results.

Is there any better way, maybe one that work straight out of the box via VSTS?

Note: Changing the build agent to run under a different account doesn't work because I need to run tests under multiple accounts long-term to test various authentication features.

Comment: The Visual Studio Test task can't run as a different user, you need to run test by using Run Functional Tests task.

Answer (score 0):

You can run the test on remote machine by using Visual Studio Test Agent Deployment and Run Functional Tests tasks.

With this way, you can specify username and password that the test agent running on (Visual Studio Test Agent Deployment task).